# recursive c++ template problem

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a template class that takes msgs from source, does something smart to them, and then sends them to a sink:

```
template <typename Source, typename Sink>
class MsgHandler
{
MsgHandler(Source* pSource)
: m_pSource(pSource)
{
  m_pSource->setHandler(this);
}
};

//Now the definition of the Source:

template <typename Handler>
class Source
{
void setHandler(Handler* pHandler)
{
  m_pHandler = pHandler;
}
};
```

All fine, but now I can't really **make** a Source or Handler. Eg:

```
MsgHandler<FileSource<MsgHandler<FileSource.... recursing parameters...
FileSource<MsgHandler<FileSource<MsgHandler.... same problem when trying to build a source
```

Is there a way to solve this problem without using a virtual base class for the Handler?

Virtual base class solution:

```
class MyHandler
{
virtual ~MyHandler() {};
virtual void handleSomething() = 0;
};

template <typename Source, typename Sink>
class MsgHandler : public MyHandler
{
  MsgHandler(Source* pSource)
  : m_pSource(pSource)
  {
    m_pSource->setHandler(this);
  }
  void handleSomething() {}
 };

class Source
{
void setHandler(MyHandler* pHandler)
{
m_pHandler = pHandler;
}
};
```

Comment: So, what's the handler *for*? We could help you refactor if we knew what the parts did. Your first code example isn't really complete, and the second only helps a bit. (Where is `handleSomething` ever called?)

Comment: handleSomething would be called from the source whenever it receives a msg. For example, imagine the source is a tcp server, it gets a packet, and calls handleSomething with the contents, the msg handler handles the packet, and when it has enough data from the source to build a logical msg, it send it to the sink. You can imagine similar situations where you read msgs from a file line by line. Doesn't really matter the context. The problem is entirely syntactic. How is this achieved? Is it impossible? Or is there some trick. I'm not looking for a refactoring. I want to know if it can be done.

Comment: if your question is can I define `A<B>` and `B<A>`, then the answer is no, as you indicated in the errors you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a templated parameter for the source parameter of your handler:

```
class MySink;
template <template<typename Handler> class Source, typename Sink>
class MsgHandler
{
    Source<MsgHandler>* m_pSource;

    MsgHandler(Source<MsgHandler>* pSource)
    : m_pSource(pSource)
    {
      m_pSource->setHandler(this);
    }
};

//Now the definition of the Source:

template <typename Handler>
class Source
{
    void setHandler(Handler* pHandler)
    {
      m_pHandler = pHandler;
    }
};

//Now you can define variables like this
MsgHandler<Source, MySink> myHandler;
```

Of course that requires the Source parameter of MsgHandler to be a template with exactly one parameter (the handler), but if you can live with that constraint this would solve your definition problem (otherwise you might (or might not depending on what exactly you would be trying) be able to use some extra template foo to circumvent this restriction (creating another template which takes the handler as parameter and has a typedef for the corresponding SourcesType comes to mind).

In this scenario it might also be a good idea to add an `typedef Source<MsgHandler> SourceType` to MsgHandler to make the Source-Instantiation visible to the caller (instead of requiring the programmer to guess that MsgHandler will instantiate Source.

Comment: Just tried this out and got it working. Neat. Going to play around with it a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your `Source` needs to be parameterized on its handler.  If `Source` and `Handler` really do need to be tightly coupled in the way you describe, it does not seem like templates buy you very much beyond interface definition.  Seems to me like you could just have a non-template `Source` class that encapsulates `Handler<Source, Sink>`.

Comment: True, your proposed solution would work but then the Source would know about the Handler. Particularly what type of handler is being used. And it would make the Source unusable if I wanted a different handler. Hence I proposed a virtual class for the Handler. I'm more interested in knowing if the problem can be solved maintaining templates. Is there some trick?

Comment: Can't think of a sensible way using class templates.  See here for a model that uses function templates instead:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `Handler` shouldn't know anything about the `Source`. How about simple linear dependency:

```
template <typename Sink>
class Handler {
private:
    Sink* sink; // get this pointer in the constructor?
public:
    void handle( const Msg& m ) {
        // processing
        sink->accept( m );
    }
};

template <typename Handler>
class Source {
private:
    Handler* handler; 
public:
    void genMessage() {
        Msg m;
        // get message off the wire?
        handler->handle( m );
    }
};
```

Could also be twisted to have "handling" and "sinking" as [policies](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.Policy-basedDesign).

Comment: True, in a perfect world the handler would not know about the source. My design is not that clean, a conscious decision that I made. Sometimes the sink will cause the handler to do something to the source. However, your solution is very clean and would work well.